# For Django's CSRF failure middleware, how can you get the CSRF errors to report what URL is failing?

Tags: django

For Django's CSRF failure middleware, how can you get the CSRF errors to report what URL is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered an error handler for csrf_failures (called csrf_failure) and the "request.path" has the url that was rejected during the CSRF failure.

```
def csrf_failure(request, reason=""):
    print "CSRF failure: reason=%s, url=%s" % (reason, request.path)
    ...
```